# C#: Avoiding if (x is Foo) {...} else if (x is Bar) {...} for data structures

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a family of data structures like:

```
abstract class Base {...}
class Foo : Base {...}
class Bar : Base {...}
```

and a method which takes a Base and converts it depending on which subclass it is:

```
void Convert(Base b) {
  if (b is Foo) 
    // Do the Foo conversion
  else if (b is Bar) 
    // Do the Bar conversion
...
```

Obviously this is terrible object orientation - the Convert method has to know about every derived class of Base and has to be changed every time that Base is extended. The 'normal' OO way of solving this problem is to make each derived class of Base responsible for converting itself, e.g.

```
abstract class Base {
  abstract Converted Convert();
...}
class Foo : Base {
  override Converted Convert(){...}
...}
class Bar : Base {
  override Converted Convert(){...}
...}
```

However, in the code that I am writing Base is a pure data structure (only getters and setters - no logic), and it is in another assembly which I do not have permission to change. Is there a way of better structuring the code that does not force the derived classes of Base to have logic?

Thanks

Comment: The visitor pattern might help

Comment: You could introduce an intermediary abstract class that inherits from Base and from which Foo and Bar inherit. Then add an abstract `Convert` method to that intermediary class.

Comment: What happens when someone extends `Base` into a new class?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a good way to solve this without being able to modify the `Base`, `Foo`, and `Bar` classes.

Comment: I'd not-answer this by criticizing the premise. Your question is "*I have an operation C that takes any B, but the author of B makes no guarantee that every sub type of B can support operation C*".  Therefore the operation C does *not* take *any B*, it only takes *some* Bs, and therefore the author of C is writing a contract that it has no intention of keeping. Don't do that.

Comment: Have `Foo` and `Bar` implement an interface defining all of the operations other methods may need to perform on them; have your method accept an argument typed to that interface.

Comment: @Servy: The author has neglected to mention in the original post that Foo and Bar are also read-only from where they are sitting.

Comment: @EricLippert I thought only base was read only.  If you're correct then yes, that's not a solution.  I posted it as a comment mostly because I wasn't sure if it was an option or not.

Comment: @Servy: Since that is what the author said, you are justified in having that belief. The additional information was added to a comment in an answer that has been deleted.

Comment: @EricLippert Ah, didn't see that comment.  You're quite right.

Answer (score 19):

If it hurts when you do that then don't do that. The fundamental problem is:

> I have a method which takes a `Base`...

Since that is the fundamental problem, remove it.  Get rid of that method entirely because it is awful.

Replace it with:

```
void Convert(Foo foo) {
   // Do the Foo conversion
}
void Convert(Bar bar) {
   // Do the Bar conversion
}
```

Now no method has to lie and say that it can convert *any* `Base` when in fact it cannot.

Comment: That only works when the compiler knows which concrete type it is at compile-time.

Comment: @JohnGibb: Correct; that is precisely the circumstance in which the code is known to be type-correct given the scenario presented by the original poster. The whole *point* of a statically analyzed language is to tell you when the program is *not known to be free of type errors*. If the programmer does not know what the type of the object is then the programmer does not know that `Convert` is a legal operation!

Comment: That's definitely true, but if the person can't edit the original types, then they don't really have a choice but to enumerate the possible subtypes. I just don't see how your answer will help them; they'd have to use casts to even get your overloads to be called!

Comment: @JohnGibb: The existence of the question does not logically imply that there is a pleasant solution. I note that the developers of classes Base, Foo and Bar did not adequately anticipate the needs of the customer. If they had then either (1) they would have provided the necessary code themselves, (2) they would have designed the class hierarchy for extensibility better, or (3) they would have designed the hierarchy so that Foo and Bar are the only possible derived types of Base.

Comment: This solution only makes sense if Convert is `public`, as there it is important to think about the method contract. If it is `private`, you already know how the method will be called so the contract is far less important and yet you're simply moving the type detection and casts from the callee to the callers, making this *less* elegant than what the OP had.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation to this, and came up with a solution that's similar to pattern matching in a functional language. Here is the syntax:

*Note that within the lambdas, foo and bar are strongly typed as their respectives types; no need to cast.*

```
var convertedValue = new TypeSwitch<Base, string>(r)
            .ForType<Foo>(foo => /* do foo conversion */)
            .ForType<Bar>(bar => /* do bar conversion */)
        ).GetValue();
```

And here is the implementation of the TypeSwitch class:

```
public class TypeSwitch<T, TResult>
{
    bool matched;
    T value;
    TResult result;

    public TypeSwitch(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public TypeSwitch<T, TResult> ForType<TSpecific>(Func<TSpecific, TResult> caseFunc) where TSpecific : T
    {
        if (value is TSpecific)
        {
            matched = true;
            result = caseFunc((TSpecific)value);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public TResult GetValue()
    {
        if (!matched)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("No case matched");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm sure it can be cleaned up, and in most cases Eric Lippert is right that this premise is fundamentally flawed. However, if you run into a case where your only other choice is a bunch of `is` and casts, I think this is a little cleaner!