# Polymorphism Through Extension Methods?

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, extension-methods

I have a class library which contain some base classes and others that are derived from them. In this class library, I'm taking advantage of polymorphism to do what I want it to do. Now in a consuming application, I want to change the behavior of some code based on the runtime type of the child classes. So assume the following:

```
public class Base { }
public class Child1 : Base { }
public class Child2 : Base { }
```

Now in the consuming application I want do something as follows (note that all of the following classes are in the consuming application and cannot be referenced in the class library):

```
public interface IMyInterface1 { }
public interface IMyInterface2 { }
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void DoSomething(this Base myObj, Object dependency)
    {

    }

    public static void DoSomething(this Child1 myObj, Object dependency)
    {
        IMyInterface1 myInterface = dependency as IMyInterface1;
        if (myInterface != null)
        {
            //Do some Child1 specific logic here
        }
    }

    public static void DoSomething(this Child2 myObj, Object dependency)
    {
        IMyInterface2 myInterface = dependency as IMyInterface2;
        if (myInterface != null)
        {
            //Do some Child2 specific logic here
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This does not work. It always calls the extension method of the base class. Is there some other way that will allow me to do this and avoid having to explicitly check for the runtime type? The reasons is because more classes that are derived from the `Base` could be added and corresponding extension methods could come from some other external assembly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try it first, then ask with details of what went wrong if necessary?

Comment: That won't work; extension methods are statically dispatched.

Comment: Consider using the visitor pattern.

Comment: Try using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958890/c-avoiding-if-x-is-foo-else-if-x-is-bar-for-data-structures/19964192#19964192

Comment: Ok so I tried it and @SLaks was right. It always calls the extension method of the base class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @SLaks has already stated you cannot call the method as an extension method (even with a `dynamic` type) ... you can however call the static method with a `dynamic` type

So, although this will fail

```
Base base1 = new Child1();
(base1 as dynamic).DoSomething();
```

This will work

```
Base base1 = new Child1();
Extensions.DoSomething(base1 as dynamic);
```

Comment: This has actually worked! Very smart I have to say! So the bottom line is that I can achieve it with a static method and calling it as you recommended, but it cannot be done using extension methods that are called on the instance, right?

Comment: That really surprises me. AFAIK, the extension methods (which don't work with dynamic) are converted by the compiler into identical static method calls (which do work). Would be interesting to see the IL in each case (but don't have access to a compiler right now). Can anyone explain why this might be?

Comment: This is amazing, deserves a lot more love, thank you

Answer (score 7):

No, that won't work.

Extension methods are statically dispatched, using the same mechanism as overload resolution.

If you have a variable of compile-time type `Base`, the compiler will always call the base extension method, regardless of the runtime type.

Instead, you can make the base extension method check the runtime type and call the appropriate other extension method.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid checking the runtime type because more classes that are derived from the `Base` could be added and corresponding extension methods could come from some other external assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing just now.

You could add one more method to your extension class like this:

```
public static void DoSomething(this Base myObj, Object dependency)
{       
    if(myObj.IsSubclassOf(Base))
    {
      // A derived class, call appropriate extension method.  
      DoSomething(myObj as dynamic, dependency);
    }
    else
    {
        // The object is Base class so handle it.
    }
}
```

You don't need the if/else check if the base class is abstract (or never used in the wild):

```
public static void DoSomething(this Base myObj, Object dependency)
{ 
    DoSomething(myObj as dynamic, dependency);
}
```

[Edit] Actually this won't work in your case as you don't implement support for all derived objects (so could still get infinite recursion). I guess you could pass something to check for recursion but the given answer is the simplest.  I'll leave this here as it might spark more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the minimal example showing how to mimic polymorphism with extension methods.

```
void Main()
{
    var elements = new Base[]{
        new Base(){  Name = "Base instance"},
        new D1(){    Name = "D1 instance"},
        new D2(){    Name = "D2 instance"},
        new D3(){    Name = "D3 instance"}

    };

    foreach(Base x in elements){
        x.Process();
    }
}

public class Base{
    public string Name;
}
public class D1 : Base {}
public class D2 : Base {}
public class D3 : Base {}


public static class Exts{

    public static void Process(this Base obj){
        if(obj.GetType() == typeof(Base)) Process<Base>(obj); //prevent infinite recursion for Base instances
        else Process((dynamic) obj);
    }

    private static void Process<T>(this T obj) where T: Base
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base/Default: {0}", obj.Name);
    }

    public static void Process(this D1 obj){
        Console.WriteLine("D1: {0}", obj.Name);
    }

    public static void Process(this D2 obj){
        Console.WriteLine("D2: {0}", obj.Name);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
    Base/Default: Base instance
    D1: D1 instance
    D2: D2 instance
    Base/Default: D3 instance
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can not use the keyword "dynamic" (older version of .NET), you can use reflection to achieve the same thing.

In place of :

```
Base base1 = new Child1();
Extensions.DoSomething(base1 as dynamic);
```

you can write :

```
Base base1 = new Child1();

MethodInfo method = typeof(Extensions).GetMethod("DoSomething", new System.Type[] { base1.GetType() });
if (method) {
    method.Invoke(new object[] { base1 });
}
```