# Extension methods with base and sub-classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, extension-methods

**UPDATE**

Requesting to re-open because the other SO answers don't have a solution, but one of the comments to the question has a solution I want to accept as it works for the scenario.

**Original Question**

I am having trouble writing extension methods with non-abstract base classes and sub-classes that select the appropriate extension method.

[Example Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jWYohJ)

I have a very simple example below (abstracted from a much bigger project) that uses the extension method "Run". The expected output is listed in the comment next to each class.

```
public class Parent { }; // Should output "Parent"
public class ChildA : Parent { }; // Should output "Child A"
public class ChildB : Parent { }; // Should output "Parent"

// Expected Output: ChildA, Parent, Parent
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var commands = new List<Parent>() { new ChildA(), new ChildB(), new Parent() };
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", commands.Select(c => c.Run())));
    }
}
```

Here are my attempts so far, but there has to be a cleaner way to do this:

1. No type-checking - Results in the Parent extension method being used exclusively (Parent, Parent, Parent)
2. Explicit type checking - Right output, but have to explicitly check types for each extension possibility (ChildA, Parent, Parent)
3. Attempted Convert.ChangeType to dynamic type - Run-time exception since extension won't catch the dynamic type (no output)
4. Attempted generic cast with reflection - not quite operational yet, but not sure if approach is even valid

**List of attempts**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Run(this ChildA model)
    {
        return "ChildA";
    }
    public static string Run(this Parent model)
    {
        return model.Run1(); // Change to test different approaches
    }
    public static string Run1(this Parent model) // No type-checking
    {
        return "Parent";
    }
    public static string Run2(this Parent model) // Explicitly check sub-types
    {
        if (model is ChildA)
            return ((ChildA)model).Run();
        else
            return "Parent";
    }
    public static string Run3(this Parent model) // Attempted dynamic type conversion
    {
        if (model.GetType().BaseType == typeof(Parent))
        {
            dynamic changedObj = Convert.ChangeType(model, model.GetType());
            return changedObj.Run();
        }
        else
            return "Parent";
    }
    public static string Run4(this Parent model) // Attempted reflected generic type conversion
    {
        if (model.GetType().BaseType == typeof(Parent))
        {
            var method = typeof(Extensions).GetMethod("Cast");
            var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { model.GetType() });
            //var generic = generic.Invoke(new object(), null);
            //return generic.Run();
            return "Not working yet";
        }
        else
            return "Parent";
    }
    public static T Cast<T>(this object input)
    {
        return (T) input;   
    }

}
```

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is polymorphism, which [isn't available for extension methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707317/polymorphism-through-extension-methods)

Comment: Polymorphism on extension methods is exactly what this is ... thanks for finding the old SO question that is basically the same thing. I liked the Visitor pattern mentioned there for what the app is doing, and any opp to change extensions into solid patterns is a good one. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: an approach with reflected methods can work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iqXu8Y

Comment: @ASh - That approach works great. I nominated this question to re-open so you can put it for an answer if you want.

Comment: It seems like the much easier way to do that is `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", commands.Select(c => Extensions.Run(c as dynamic))));`  Taken from the link by @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @KyleW - Thanks for the suggestion - that works perfectly as well and I missed the dynamic cast makes the type selection work for the methods

Comment: @JasonW I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the two extension methods for `Parent` and `ChildA`, you can move the association to runtime by using `dynamic`.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", commands.Select(c => Extensions.Run(c as dynamic))));
```

Comment: i added an answer with some pitfalls of `dynamic`. please, read

Answer (score 1):

the best Run method overload is resolved at compile-time and for items of  `List<Parent>` it is `Run(this Parent model)`. Polymorphic behavior can be imitated using reflection in extension method

[demonstration](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iqXu8Y)

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Extensions
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> _runs;
    private static Type  _parentType;

    static Extensions()
    {
        _parentType = typeof(Parent);        
        _runs = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();

        // overloads of Run method, which return string for different types derived from Parent
        var methods = typeof(Extensions)
                      .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public)
                      .Where(m => m.Name == "Run" && m.ReturnType == typeof(string));

        foreach(var mi in methods)
        {
            var args = mi.GetParameters();
            //  method should have only one parameter
            if (args.Length != 1 || _parentType.IsAssignableFrom(args[0].ParameterType) == false)
                return;         
            _runs.Add(args[0].ParameterType, mi);
        }

    }
```

// overloads

```
    public static string Run(this ChildA model)
    {
        return "ChildA";
    }

    public static string Run(this Parent model, object args)
    {
        // this method is not added to _runs (2 parameters)
        return null;
    }

    public static int Run(this ChildC model)
    {
        // this method is not added to _runs (return int)
        return 0;
    }

    public static string Run(this Parent model) // Attempted dynamic type conversion
    {               
        // not really correct
        if (model == null)
            return "Parent";            
        var t = model.GetType();
        if (t == _parentType)       
            return "Parent";
        // invoke overload for type t
        if (_runs.ContainsKey(t))       
            return (string) _runs[t].Invoke(null, new object[] {model});        
        return "Not working yet";
    }       
}
```

// usage

```
public class Parent { };          // Should output "Parent"
public class ChildA : Parent { }; // Should output "Child A"
public class ChildB : Parent { }; // Should output "Not working yet"
public class ChildC : Parent { };

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var commands = new List<Parent>() { new ChildA(), new ChildB(), new Parent(),  new ChildC(), (ChildA)null};
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", commands.Select(c => c.Run())));

        // extension method can be invoked for null
        Console.WriteLine(((ChildA)null).Run());

        //// crashes on (ChildA)null with error: 
        //// The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Extensions.Run(ChildA)' and 'Extensions.Run(ChildC)'
        //Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", commands.Select(c => Extensions.Run(c as dynamic))));
    }
}
```

resume

extension method can be invoked as common method (`.Run()`), not as static `Extensions.Run`

extension method `Run(this Parent model)` has problems with `null` argument (cannot resolve type correct)

trick with `dynamic` works in most situations, but :

1. invokes `int Run(this ChildC model)` method, which returns `int` not `string` like others (when `(ChildA)null` is removed from list)
2. crashes with `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Extensions.Run(ChildA)' and 'Extensions.Run(ChildC)'` error (i don't understand that)